# How to set permission for a User

Tags: community, profile, permission-sets, user-management

I have 20 users having the same profile and having CRED as well as ViewAll permissions. I want to remove the viewAll permission for a single user, what are all the possible ways to achieve this?

I have two answers- One is to create a new profile for this user, another one is to remove the viewAll permission for all users, and allow it in a permission set and assign that set to the other 19 users. Are there any other possible ways?

Comment: I certainly suggest the perm set approach, the assignment of which you can achieve with a tiny amount of scripting with sfdx CLI. Profiles should no longer be used for more or less anything but license and page layout assignment (plus a few minor exceptions where profiles provide capabilities not available through perm sets or perm set groups).

Comment: Muting permission set looks like a good option here. More info [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.perm_set_groups_muting.htm&type=5)